# How can i optimize SUM() mysql Query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a mysql SUM query that runs on more than 0.6 million records. 
what i am currently doing is like this

```
 SELECT SUM (payment)
    FROM payment_table
    WHERE
       payment_date BETWEEN ... AND ...
       AND
       payment_status = 'paid'
```

I changed the query to this format to reduce the recordset but it is still taking almost same time.

```
SELECT SUM(Payments)
FROM (
    SELECT payment AS Payments FROM payment_table WHERE
     payment_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '2012-2-01') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '2012-2-01')), '%Y-%m-%d')
    AND
    payment_status = 'paid'
) AS tmp_table
```

Is their any way to optimize this sum query.
EDIT:

This is the result when query is run with `EXPLAIN`

> insert into `` ` ( ``id`,`select_type`,`table`,`type`,`possible_keys`,`
>   key`,`key_len`,`ref`,`rows`,`Extra`)
>   values('1','SIMPLE','lps','index_merge','assigned_user_id,scheduled_payment_date,payment_status,deleted','deleted,assigned_user_id,payment_status','2,109,303',NULL,'23347','Using
>   intersect(deleted,assigned_user_id,payment_status); Using where');

Comment: use >= and <= instead of between and try again

Comment: now it takes almost 4 times more than the original query

Comment: Create an index on payment_date.

Comment: i have created the index on payment_date and payment

Comment: Can you paste your explain result on the first statement?

Comment: add group by payments. This should reduce it!

Comment: What datatype is the payment_date column, and what exact values are you using for the between values?

Comment: @raheelshan I can say with confidence that you completely have no idea of what you are talking about. Best not to give advice unless you actually know it is good advice

Comment: @Bohemian payment_date is of Date type. and for the between values i am using like >  BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '2012-2-01') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '2012-2-01')), '%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: When payment_date is really of type `date` you don't need the `DATE_FORMAT()` but you should use `CUR_DATE()` instead of `NOW()`. Also please put the word `EXPLAIN` in front of your query and post the result.

Comment: As @tombom mentioned, look at the output of `EXPLAIN`, or better, `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`

Comment: In addition to tomboms comment, despite using NOW(), your dates will be constants as you have given dates rather than a date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should match the data type of the preducate with the column. Because `payment_type` is `DATE`, make the BETWEEN values `DATE` also:

```
 WHERE payment_date BETWEEN
     CURDATE() AND LAST_DAY(CURDATE())
```

Matching types ensures the index will be used.

In contrast, your query is using `DATE_FORMAT()`, which produces a *text* data type, so in order to perform the comparison, mysql is converting the `payment_dare` column to text, so it can't use the index (the index contains `DATE` values, not text values), so *every single row* is converted and compared.

If you are still having performance problems after making the change above, execute this:

```
ANALYZE TABLE payment_table;
```

Which will check the distribution of values in the indexed columns, which helps mysql make the right choice of index.

Comment: The dates used in the Between Clause are dynamic, i.e. User provides those dates so what format should be used to convert that to the proper MySQL format, i thought DATE_FORMAT will do the trick.

Comment: What if i calculate the dates in PHP like BETWEEN '2012-2-01' AND '2012-02-29', what effect will this carry.

Comment: I'm not familiar with php drivers, but try to pass a "date" object (perhaps calling a typed method to set the parameter), but if that's not possible, creating a string query using values like you have mentioned should be fine. Run an "explain" on the query as passed to mysql to be sure the index is being used.

Comment: when i run explain on using the above mentioned values of my comment i get "index_merge" in the Type column, is it using the index by saying this.